# WCF and Access 95

Tags: wcf, ms-access, x86, oledb

First, don't be hatn'. I know people born when MS stopped supporting Access 95 are now in high school. I am trying to provide a path forward.

I have a WCF being developed on my Win 8.1 64 bit computer (VS 2013). When my unit test makes the call, the WCF it needs to query the DB and return a dataset. I do this using traditional dataAdapter.fill() call. This causes a 'Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on local the machine.' error.  I have found several posts on this forum that state the 4.0 driver will not work in a 64 bit application. So I have set the solution platform to 'x86', in the project properties i set the platform to 'Active (x86)'.  When I set the platform Target to 'x86' and try to run I receive another error 'system BadImageFormatException....' so I had to switch it back to 'Any'. The error persists.

Next I thought VS web service host was run 64 bit. I installed IIS on my local dev machine and setup the project there and set the App Pool to enable 32 bit application = true, no change.  Then I tried moving the dlls to sysWOW64 and register them there, still no luck. I tried to set corflags with '/32bit+' parameter, only to learn the file has no headers, so it can't be set. Finally, I upgraded to the ver. 12 driver and changed to connection string only to get an almost identical error,  'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on local the machine.'

I am open to any suggestions at this point.  I probably missed some small detail back at the beginning of all this.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It does sound like your WCF service code is running in the 64-bit realm. Can you get your service to show you the result of `IntPtr.Size * 8` to positively indicate the "32" or "64" bitness?

Comment: IT is running 32 bit.  Now I am really confused.